# Is it possible to Mock ExecuteReader method which has 'SqlDataReader' as a return type using MOQ' framework?

Tags: c#, moq, sqldatareader

I am working on Integration Test scripts using 'Moq' framework. Would like to know the possible ways to mock Execute Reader method which has 'SqlDataReader' as a return type.

```cs
//Code which needs to mock

List<list> li = new List<list>();

query = "some query as input";
using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = databaseWrapper.ExecuteReader(query, null))
{
    if (sqlDataReader != null)
    {
        if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
        {
            while (sqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                R1 rm = new R1
                {
                    r3 = Convert.ToString(sqlDataReader["Name"]),
                    r4 = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["Id"])
                };
                li.Add(rm);
            }
        }

        rR.li = li;
        return rR;
    }
}
```

As I have researched we can mock IDataReader but no 'SqlData Reader' since 'SqlDataReader does not have any constructor.

Did anyone tried in different way to mock the 'SqlDataReader'. Please help me on this.

Comment: Take it a level higher. There is no real incentive to mock this code; mock the calling code instead. You want to mock the `List` of objects that's the result, not the inner code that converts from the database. If for some reason you really wanted to test the code that maps from the data reader to an object, refactoring it to a separate method that works on `IDataReader` would be your best chance. For an actual *integration test*, you shouldn't be mocking at all: use a real database (like a LocalDB instance where you deploy a database project to).

Comment: how do u even mock a class? u can mock only interfaces or base classes as much as i know

Comment: Don't moq the reader or write unit tests for it. You want to unit test logic. Did you look at the moq documentation? https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart